# PHP includes or plain hard coded

Tags: php

Would a website load faster using PHP includes, or by hard coding them into the pages themselves?

I would primarily use the PHP for the header and footer, using this statement:

```
<?php require("header.php") ?>
```

Comment: Use a profiler and find out that you wasted your time thinking about this.

Comment: why hardcode? the main reason to use PHP as a beginner is for templating.

Comment: If your HDD (or SSD) is utter garbage then it wouldn't matter since it's take ages anyways, but it's 2016. Does ~15ms really matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, including files won't have any negative performance impact that's significant at all. This is an example of [Premature Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

When you're running PHP code in Production, you should be using an OpCode Cache, like the Zend OpCode Cache built in to PHP 5.6+. In such a cached setting, there is literally no difference whatsoever. Even uncached, the difference will never be noticeable. You will have much more low-hanging fruit to optimize.

As far as webpage load times, this will especially not be noticeable at all. The HTTP request itself will be the "slow" part.

Comment: Thank you! Better answer than Mario's.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you!